# SQLAlchemy query.all() behavior

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Something I'm noticing after turning on some debugging in my SQLAlchemy app, is a statement like this:

`self.session.query(User).all()`

seems to be running one query for each row in the table.

i.e.

`select * from user where id = 1`

`select * from user where id = 2`.

`select * from user where id = n`.

I would expect just a simple `select * from user` to be issued.  Is this expected behavior or something poorly configured in my application?

Comment: That's not expected. Please post your model configuration.

Comment: Agreed. Definitely not expected. Potentially an issue with a lazy-loaded relationship

Answer (score 0):

So, it turned out to be related to transactional scoping and the Flask_RESTPlus `marshal_with` decorator.  I basically had this:

```
@api.marshal_with(User)
def get(self):
    with transaction_scope(current_app.dbsession):
        return self.user_service.get_users(), 200
```

where `transaction_scope` basically scopes the interaction with the DB in a transaction.

However, this was causing the decorator to attempt to marshal the response outside the scope of the transaction, so it saw stale objects and was rehydrating them as it processed them, resulting in the numerous queries.

I changed it to this:

```
def get(self):
    with transaction_scope(current_app.dbsession):
        return api.marshal(self.user_service.get_users(), User), 200
```

which solved the problem.

TL;DR - the marshal_with decorator has some unexpected behavior when running it outside of a transaction.